# How to pairing with a medical device through Bluetooth?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a tonometer https://medical.andonline.com/a-and-d-connect-app

I trying to make a mobile app for this.
I pairing with him throw Bluetooth, read all characteristics but indicator does not change from 'Pr' to 'End' It changed to 'SET' and nothing happen, after a couple seconds device disconnect.

A&D medical developers have an examples - https://github.com/andengineering  but it does not work for me too and no one updated code in repos.

Answer (score 0):

After turning on the notification for the measurement characteristic, you must issue a disconnect(). Then ‘end’ will appear